# Issue with Line Graph in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I am pulling my hair our trying to format a line graph.

Below is my current report - :

[image]

The Line Graph I have created has a Category Group of "YearLogged" and "MonthLogged".

The series I have added is an expression  -

**=Count(IIF(Fields!InvoicePaid_.Value = "Yes" And Fields!ProcessTarget.Value = "InTarget", 1, Nothing))**

As you can see the data label is coming back as values in "Paid" column from my table. What I want is the percentages instead labelled.

Also the Y axis is coming back with the total Paid invoices as a percentage? That's not right I want that to show up to 100%.

I just want to show what % of invoices are being paid In Target over the month.

Another question - where is the legend title getting "Process Target" from? Can I rename that to what ever I want?

Comment: Sorry I've highlighted the wrong columns its the In Target and % that I am interested in next to what I have highlighted. Thanks

Comment: If I am assuming this correctly then u need till 100% in the Y axis and ur line graph would show the same value?

Comment: Hi, I need the Y axis to show from 0% to 100% depending on how many Invoices were paid in target. Those figures are the 797, 797, 304 and the % next to them that I want on the graph - not the ones I have incorrectly highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this to work -

added the following expression to my series.

**=SUM(IIF(Fields!InvoicePaid_.Value = "Yes" And Fields!PaidTarget.Value = "InTarget", 1, 0))/Count(IIF(Fields!InvoicePaid_.Value = "Yes", 1, Nothing))**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem for the line in your chart is that it is based on the number of records that meet your criteria rather than a percentage of the total. Apparently you changed the axis for a percentage but that doesn't aggregate the data for you. You'll need to change your formula to something like:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!InvoicePaid_.Value = "Yes" And Fields!ProcessTarget.Value = "InTarget", 1, 0)) / COUNTROWS()
```

The Legend uses the name of your field or a custom name in the Label field of the Values. In the Values' **Series Properties** Legend tab, you can use Custom Legend Text. If it's just one line as in your chart, I usually remove the legend altogether.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply but that doesn't work. If I divide by COUNTROWS() I get a completely different % figure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=CDec(Count(IIF(Fields!InvoicePaid_.Value = "Yes" And Fields!ProcessTarget.Value = "InTarget", 1, Nothing))) / CDec(Count(IIF(Fields!InvoicePaid_.Value = "Yes", 1, Nothing)))
```

I simply took your expression and divided it by the number of invoices that were paid.  These two numbers were converted to decimals so the division would give you accurate results.

From there, you should format the number as a percentage using the `Number` tab in the series/category/chart properties, and give it however many decimal places you like.